# List of ASP.Net MVC "special" folders/files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

Is there a list of the "special" folders and files in ASP.Net MVC?  I'm talking about things like "Views/Shared/EditorTemplates" and "Views/_ViewStart.cshtml."

**EDIT:**
Responding to CodeIgnoto's comment, I'm not asking about general architecture or how to create a site. I want a list of all the "special" folders and files that the ASP.Net MVC uses. There appear to be quite a few poorly documented features of the ASP.Net MVC framework that could be extremely useful. When I stumbled upon the EditorTemplates and DisplayTemplates folders, I was shocked that they weren't really documented anywhere.

Comment: if you are looking for general architecture of your project,have a look at http://sharparchitecture.net/

Comment: Have an upvote for "not really documented" as blogs are no documentation. Reading up on MVC features is a tedious practice of reverse engineering through tons of blogs. Anyway I don't think this is a valid SO question.

Comment: CodeCaster: I completely agree about the tediousness of researching ASP.Net MVC. I continue to discover "magic" within the framework; which is cool and all. But it's extremely frustrating!  BTW, how is this not a valid question?

Answer (score 2):

I think they should be `_Layout.cshtml`, `App_Codes`, `App_LocalResosources`, `App_GlobalResources`, `Themes`, `Global.asax`, `Web.config`...

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2013, MSDN has a [page on general ASP.NET folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx) that is relatively complete, but I couldn't find anything more up-to-date than [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410120%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) for MVC.

My search wasn't exactly extensive, but this document is the most relevant one that is referenced on the official website, so I guess you're right in that something is lacking here.

Unofficial or semi-official information seems to be enough for most people.  If you want a definitive reference though, [the sources](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) are available.

Comment: This list is far from complete.  It doesn't list anything about ASP.Net MVC ("Controllers" folder, "Views" folder, etc.).

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that the `Controllers`, `Models` and `Views` folders are required.  Instead, I think MVC uses conventions for CLI class names (possibly namespaces, but even that I'm not certain of either) to determine the routes at runtime.  The compiler has nothing to do with routing AFAIK.  In fact, all these files will all end up in arbitrary DLLs (usually the same one), so their location on the filesystem is irrelevant.  **Edit:**  Except for Razor files, obviously, which have nothing to do with routing.